# what does Map() fork the pipeline is called between the EndpointRoutingMiddleware and EndpointMiddleware mean?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes

https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/Builder/EndpointRoutingApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs,150

I am reading the source code of `EndpointRoutingApplicationBuilderExtensions` which has the following method:

```
private static void VerifyEndpointRoutingMiddlewareIsRegistered(IApplicationBuilder app, out IEndpointRouteBuilder endpointRouteBuilder) {
   if (!app.Properties.TryGetValue(EndpointRouteBuilder, out var obj)) {  // I can understand this part
       var message = "...";
       throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
   }
  
   endpointRouteBuilder = (IEndpointRouteBuilder)obj!;

   // This check handles the case where Map or something else that forks the pipeline is called between the two routing middleware 
   if (endpointRouteBuilder is DefaultEndpointRouteBuilder defaultRouteBuilder && !object.ReferenceEquals(app, defaultRouteBuilder.ApplicationBuilder)) {
      var message = $"The {nameof(EndpointRoutingMiddleware)} and {nameof(EndpointMiddleware)} must be added to the same {nameof(IApplicationBuilder)} instance. " +
          $"To use Endpoint Routing with 'Map(...)', make sure to call '{nameof(IApplicationBuilder)}.{nameof(UseRouting)}' before " +
          $"'{nameof(IApplicationBuilder)}.{nameof(UseEndpoints)}' for each branch of the middleware pipeline.";
      throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
   }
}
```

I don't understand the second part, does it mean that `Map(...)` is called before `UseRouting()` and `UseEndpoints()` as:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {

   app.UseRouting();


   app.Map("/branch", app => {
      await context.Response.WriteAsync("branch detected");
   });


   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
      endpoints.MapGet("routing", async context => {
         await context.Response.WriteAsync("Request Was Routed");
      });
   });


   app.Use(async (context, next) => {
      await context.Response.WriteAsync("Terminal Middleware Reached");
      await next();
   });
}
```

I can't see any wrong with the above code, so what does the source code mean, how can I reproduce an error as that method show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example exercise the code you've highlighted:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseRouting();

    app.Map("/branch", branchApp =>
    {
        branchApp.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            // ...
        });
    });

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        // ...
    });
}
```

As the error message suggests, this is to make sure you have a matching pair of `UseRouting` and `UseEndpoints` for each branch of the middleware pipeline. In the example I've shown, there's a missing call to `branchApp.UseRouting()`, so this triggers the error.